# How to get meta head data in Rank Math plugin in JSON format

Tags: json, wordpress, metadata

I am using the Rank Math plugin and I would like to retrieve the meta header data in JSON format. Could you help me?

The Rank Math plugin returns the meta head data in HTML format, but I want the data to be returned in JSON format.

for example:

return data is :

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="home" />
<meta property="og:description" content="test" />
```

but i want :

```
{"head":{"title":"home","description":"test"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Headless CMS Support option

[image: Headless CMS Support]

https://rankmath.com/kb/headless-cms-support/

---

**Update:**

Rank Math headless option actually return html meta tags, You can analyze html or use this functions:

```
<?php

use RankMath\OpenGraph\Facebook;
use RankMath\OpenGraph\OpenGraph;

/**
 * Plugin Name:       Test
 * Version:           1.0
 * Plugin URI:        https://parsa.ws
 * Description:       Test
 * Author:            Parsa
 */
class TestRankMath
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp', [$this, 'init']);
    }

    function init()
    {
        if (is_single()) {
            $Facebook  = new Facebook();
            $OpenGraph = new OpenGraph();
            var_dump($Facebook->locale(false));
            var_dump($Facebook->type(false));
            var_dump($Facebook->title(false));
            var_dump($OpenGraph->get_title());
            var_dump($OpenGraph->get_description());
        }
    }
}

new TestRankMath();
```